# Software for calculating Bessel functions with an imaginary index

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm posting this in several places at once to improve response.
I've come across an ODE in waveguide problems that can be identified as Bessel's equation with an imaginary index.  The formal definition makes sense but I cannot find software that will evaluate this.  I've checked boost and matlab.  There are a few recent articles about these functions from NIST but they are all theoretical and to not cover implementation.

So, I am reaching out to see if anyone knows of either (1) an open source implementation of these functions, or (2) a transform that allows these functions to be expresses in terms of known functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is the so-called **Amos library** (written in Fortram), see http://www.netlib.org/amos/
or https://github.com/JuliaLang/openspecfun/tree/master/amos.

See also https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19902
with a link to a C++ wrapper at https://blog.joey-dumont.ca/complex_bessel/
or https://github.com/valandil/complex_bessel.

**Disclaimer** I have not tested the libraries.

Comment: Found a NIST lib that cited complex order and argument which is what I need.  Don't know why I didn't see it in previous searches.  Probably because it's FORTRAN and I've been looking for C++.  I will check you other sources too.

Answer (score 0):

For some analytic results about these functions: Lebedev has done a lot of work on Bessel $K_{ i\nu}(x)$ functions. These seem to pop up when solving equations in cylindrical coordinates.

Lebedev's book "Special Functions and Their Applications", particularly Chapter 5, has a chance of being of some use (on page 140 I am seeing an asymptotic expansion of $K_{ i\nu}(x)$ for fixed $x>0$ and large $|\nu| \to \infty$).

Maybe it's worth a shot look at some resources involving [Kontorovich–Lebedev transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontorovich%E2%80%93Lebedev_transform) too; this is an integral transform using $K_{ i\nu}(x)$ as a kernel.

Comment: Thank you.  In fact I do have theoretical resources that demonstrate the series for Bessel of imaginary order, and the asymptotic limits.  However, as luck would have it, I need to (would like to) perform the calculations for inputs that do not correspond to either the extreme near or far limits.  My query is to find an implementation so I don't need to write the code from scratch.

Comment: Could you give an example of the sort of functions you're dealing with and need evaluating? I have an integral expression for a combination $K_{i\nu}(x)K_{i\nu}(y)$ in terms of simpler functions.

Comment: $$ K_{i\nu}(x) K_{i\nu}(y) = \int_0^\infty du\ K_0\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + 2 x y \cosh(u)}\right) \cos(\nu u) $$

Comment: Greg.Paul, thanks.  I'll need to dig up the old work and look.  It appears as a wave guide modes for a wave equation in refractive media.  Expressing the Green's function in terms of modes would involve exactly the above expression.  One thing I wanted to do (some time ago) was generate plots of the real and imaginary parts of the modes, with amplitude and phase, and compare to the free space case (pure sine and cosine).